# Переход из ExpandableListView в WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, expandablelistview

Как из ExpandableListView по нажатию элемента списка переходить в WebView?
Есть такой код:(ExpandableListView)

```
public class activity_stigmata_detail extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mGroupsArray = new String[] { ".....", "....", };

private String[] mWinterMonthsArray = new String[] { "..","..."", };
private String[] mSpringMonthsArray = new String[] {  "..","...",};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Stigmata");

    Map<String, String> map;

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList<>();


    for (String group : mGroupsArray) {

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("groupName", group);   
      groupDataList.add(map);
    }

    String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "groupName" };
    int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();



    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String month : mWinterMonthsArray) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("monthName", month); 
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
    }

    сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

    сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String month : mSpringMonthsArray) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("monthName", month);
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
    }
    сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);



    String childFrom[] = new String[] { "monthName" };

    int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupDataList,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom, childTo);

    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

В ListView можно было сделать так:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail_4);


    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(activity_stigmata_detail_4.this, activity_stigmata_detail_4_view.class);

            intent.putExtra("title", position);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Код из WebView

```
public class activity_stigmata_detail_4_view extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail_4_view);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String resName = "q" + intent.getIntExtra("title", 0);
    Log.i("name", resName);
    Context context = getBaseContext(); 


    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
            "raw"));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}


private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

Пытался найти в интернете ответ на свой вопрос,но так нужного и не нашёл.